# Why does my outlet tester show that my new, ungrounded outlets are grounded?

Tags: wiring

I recently installed lights and outlets in our detached garage. This home is an older home built in the 1950's and currently ungrounded. To test my newly installed lights/outlets in the garage, using an extension cord from an ungrounded source and hooking it on to the newly installed circuits, everything works fine. Using my outlet tester, it showed everything was wired correctly. I would think it should show an "open ground" but it doesn't. I double checked my wiring and it appears to be fine. I DID ground the lights/outlets to the metal boxes which they are attached to.

Comment: Something's grounded somewhere. Hard for us to say where.

Comment: When you extended this circuit, where did you attach the ground wire to on the existing circuit??

Comment: With a typical 3-light tester the light that shows that ground is good technically only means that there is 120v between hot and ground, which normally means that ground and neutral are at the same potential (because they are connected somewhere).  So, if neutral is tied to ground anywhere in the circuit it will show a "good ground".

Comment: The tester really only tells you that you "have a functional ground but didn't know it before" **or** "neutral and ground improperly connected". How do you know which one? If you are basing this simply on "my old receptacles are 2-prong" then you actually *may* have a proper ground via conduit. Or do you have other specific reasons to know you really **don't** have ground?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I fairly recently purchased this old home with a detached garage. Someone in the past ran electrical to the garage from an old switched porch light overhead into the garage (a clothesline) to power the garage door opener. Nothing in this house is currently grounded. I'm in the process of redoing the entire electrical system from the service entrance.   .

Answer (score 2):

> I DID ground the lights/outlets to the metal boxes which they are attached to.

Are your wires in metal conduit? If so, you have grounded circuits and the tester is correct.

In any case, on **new** installations everything should be grounded. Old stuff can get away without connecting a proper ground but not new. Ground for new circuits has to make its way all the way back to the panel.

In addition, receptacles in a garage normally need to be GFCI protected either at the receptacle or the breaker. It is possible to install GFCI *without* an actual ground, but (a) that is not ideal and (b) that is normally only to retrofit some protection to receptacles that have no ground available. But the ground wire and GFCI perform different functions so having both where required - that always means ground, but GFCI only in certain locations - is the gold standard.

Comment: You have to be careful when extending circuits, though; connecting all the grounds to each other but not to a proper reference ground will make them an "island" which will not ground anything, and the first ground fault will pull all the grounds up to "hot" ..

Comment: To the lights on the circuit I did use aluminum flex conduit. I also used a piece of M.C. cable to run power to the lights. As stated previously, all fixtures and outlets are grounded to their respective fixtures/boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You have a ground fault somewhere in this.  It is connecting neutral to ground, which it definitely should not do.

It's not a hot-ground fault (the usually worrisome kind), it's a neutral-ground fault.  It is likely because of a wiring error or ground wire in a box hitting a neutral screw.  Or it may be a ground fault in an appliance.

Divide and conquer until you find it.

Oh, and if a subpanel is involved, most likely someone erroneously tied the neutral and ground bar together, or wired it like a main panel is allowed to be with all the neutrals and grounds spammed onto the same bar.  That is wrong for a subpanel; neutrals and grounds must be separated.